# Amazon Route 53 Name Doesn't Resolve to Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the first time AWS for anything for me so I'm a complete newbie to this subject.

I registered a name with Route 53 and am using S3 using the static website settings there. I followed AWS's tutorial on setting up a static website from the Route 53 side (to the best of my knowledge). Currently, if I put mydomain.com into the browser url it will give me DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN or some similar "site not found" type error. When I check with whois, the domain shows up as registered. If I ping mydomain.com I get "unknown host". If I ping the S3 endpoint of mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com it gives proper results. Also, if I put in mydomain.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com into a browser it redirects to mydomain.com like it should.

Here is the view of the Route 53 control panel for the record of my domain (minus the domain name):
[image: Route 53 Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add CNAME or A (with Alias) pointing to S3 Website endpoint to the domain in Route 53?

Comment: I'm using A with Alias that points to s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

Comment: And the domain is delegated to use Route53 as name servers? https://www.whatsmydns.net look for NS records for your domain here

Comment: As far as I know it is using Route 53 as name servers, yes. If I put it into that tool, however it comes back with nothing.

Comment: After buying the domain with Rout53, you will need to add NS records. I dont know if Route53 will add it automatically. see: "Adding or Changing Name Servers and Adding or Changing Glue Records" section in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html?console_help=true#domain-register You will also first need to create a Hosted Zone for this domain. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html?console_help=true

Comment: @RakeshBollampally - please see image in post. I  believe I have created the hosted zone and NS records.

Comment: I understand you added A records but you also need to delegate the DNS for the domain to Route53. See the first link. This will be in the area where you bought the domain.

Comment: i have the same problem here.. i registered a domain, validated the email, added the records set but nothing happens..Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @Shide - I never did resolve the problem. Eventually I just gave up on it. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @GenericJam : thanks ! i managed to find a solution : create a bucket (w/ same name as my website) with a simple redirection : "Website hosting -> Redirect all requests". Worked like a charm, though i'd liked not to spend a whole afternoon on finding a solution..

Answer (score 2):

here's an answer from the comments :

Assuming you registered "mydomain.com"

In S3 :

- Create a Bucket with your domain name (optional, not sure the name has something to do with it appearing or not in your Route 53 aliases)
- Add Public permissions so that anyone can list it (to be verified)
- Add public routing policy (samples can be easily found)
- in the properties, go to "Static Website hosting", then select "Redirect all requests" and enter to URL where to send them : www.mydomain.com

In route 53 :

- Select your hosted zone "mydomain.com"
- Create a new record set : type : IPV4, alias : yes
- Alias target : this is where you select the S3 bucket you just created
  and that's it, save and it should be just fine.

hope this will keep you from wasting hours on the subject.

Also know that for obscure reasons, i've seen that some bucket would not appear immediately

Answer (score -1):

My Bad i didn't read question properly.

Select your bucket and in properties you will find option of 'static website hosting' in that check 'Enable website hosting'. Make required files in the bucket as public. In Route 53 use Endpoint of bucket as MX records, CNAME records, and A records.

Comment: The question is not about EC2.  OP is using S3 static website hosting.